# How to name api routing on a webhost sub folder

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have always thought the api controllers where not found by physical paths. The reason I ask is I have a website example.com  I created a folder example.com/testing and uploaded my project to there.  When I ran it I got errors saying that none of the apiControllers could be found. So I changed /api/apiCustomers to /testing/api/apiCustomers. It then worked,  well not the actual posting of any new records. It did locate and retrieve all the records from the database though. But it doesn't seem like that is what I would actually need to do? I have a domain  with WinHost and the default publish folder is example.com/myApp 
AM I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Have you tried `~/api/apiCustomers`?

Comment: works, put in answer so i can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle request where you do not know the root path, you can use (as in ASP.NET) the ~-character like this:

```
~/api/apiCustomers
```

~ will then be replaced by the root (i.e. `/api/apiCustomers` for prod and `/testing/api/apiCustomers` for your test environment)